# How to attach UrhoSharp Surface to LinearLayout in ViewGroup class

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, urhosharp, urho3d

I'm trying to add a UrohSharp Surface to a `LinearLayout` in a class inheriting from `ViewGroup` (to place in in the left hand corner of another view).

Most examples showing UrhoSharp implemented in Android is done directly in the main activity like this:

```cs
protected override async void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            var mLayout = new AbsoluteLayout(this);
            surface = UrhoSurface.CreateSurface(this);// (this, , true);
            mLayout.AddView(surface);

            SetContentView(mLayout);

            dronModel = await surface.Show<DroneScene>(new ApplicationOptions("Data"));
}
```

Or with a element in the layout file:

```xml
    <Urho.Droid.UrhoSurfacePlaceholder
        android:id="@+id/DroidModelId"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
```

And replace it like so:

```cs
public override async void OnViewCreated(Android.Views.View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
            base.OnViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

            surface = UrhoSurface.CreateSurface(base.Activity);
            UrhoSurfacePlaceholder parent = view.FindViewById<UrhoSurfacePlaceholder>(Resource.Id.DroidModelId);
            parent.AddView(surface);
            droneModel = await surface.Show<DroneModel>(new ApplicationOptions("Data"));
```

But, what I need to do is create a view of some sort to incapsle the Urho code and reference it somehow like this:

```xml
    <My.App.Droid.Views.Drone.Model.DroneModelView
        android:id="@+id/DroneModel2"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:background="@null"/>
```

And then grab it from the main activity view:

```cs
droneModelView = FindViewById<DroneModelView>(Resource.Id.DroneModel2);
```

Since `UrhoSurface.CreateSurface` needs the Activity object I'm not sure how to best approch this - as far as I know there is no "clean" way to reach the activity from a class inherithing `ViewGroup`? The end goal is to show the 3D model in a view containing lots of other elements that are referenced in a similar fashion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a simple example which add RatingBar to LinearLayout in CustomView,you could refer to it,change the RatingBar to your UrohSharp Surface

https://stackoverflow.com/a/57764198/10768653

Comment: Thanks, gave me the idea.